# Checkbox using images,:before tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create custom checkbox using before and images.My code is

```
<label for="gbx">
    <input type="checkbox" name="gbx" id="gbx">
    <span>12344</span>
</label>
```

Css code here

```
input {
    display: none;
}

span:before{
    content: "s";
    display: block;
    background-image: url("3_.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    background-size: cover;
}

input:checked+ span:before{
    content: "vijay";
    display: block;
    background-image: url("2_.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But it is appearing only content is present. If I decrease font-size image also decreasing its size. Why?

Answer (score 5):

You are trying in wrong way.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {visibility:hidden;}
div label:before {content:'';width:10px;height:10px;background:#fff;border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;}
div input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before{background:red;}

.new span:before{content:'';width:10px;height:10px;background:#fff;border:1px solid green; display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;}
.new input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span:before {background:green;}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="working" >
  <label for="working" >For my checkbox</label>
</div>



<label class="new">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span>2nd way</span>
</label>
```

Check out this

Comment: The way OP showed also works. because label is associated element to input tag. You can either keep the input inside the label or outside as you shown.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion nice way.  @Mr_green

Answer (score 1):

The way you structure the HTML, you don't need to mention `for` and `id` attributes to `label` and `input` respectively. You need to mention those when the HTML structure is like this:

```
<label for="gbx"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="gbx"></input>
```

But when you are nesting, they aren't necessary:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"></input>
</label>
```

Here is the code (*check the comments*):

```css
input {
  /* don't use display: none */
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
span:before {   
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
:checked + span:before {
  /* no need of mentioning content here again as you alread did in the above code */
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="gbx">
  <span>12344</span>
</label>
```